# How do I calculate resistance when I have the voltage drop?

Tags: voltage, resistance, light, ldr

This is my circuit:

3 volts in with a 1k ohm resistor in series with the LDR.

I have the voltage drop across the LDR but I need to find the resistance.

Comment: Why have you removed the schematic? It's worth a lot more than words!

Answer (score 10):

Let the resistance of the LDR be R.  R and the 1k resistor form a voltage divider, and we know the total voltage across both is 3V.  So we get

```
V = 3 R / (R + 1000)
```

Solve this to find R.

Answer (score 2):

You need the current. You could either measure it directly with your meter, or you could use the voltage across the 1K resistor and the fact you know its a 1K resistor to calculate the current through the resistor. Since the resistor is in series with the LDR, the current through both should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's a voltage divider, basic rule:

```
R1/V1 = R2/V2      with V1 = V - V2  (V = 3V; V2 = Drop)
```

You can derive it using

```
I = V / R = V / (R1 + R2)    and   V2 = I * R2 => I = V2 / R2
```

Just some basic math left and you get the above, and finally:

```
R2 = (V2 * R1) / V1 = (V2 * R1) / (V - V2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the ball flat..

Current in both elements is the same.

V = voltage measured
RLDR = resistance of LDR

I = V / RLDR = (3 - V) / 1kOhm

**RLDR = (V * 1kOhm) / (3 - V)**

Answer (score 0):

The voltage from the battery is shared between the LDR and resistor in proportion to their individual resistances. For instance, if the LDR  in this circuit has a resistance of 2kΩ, it would have two thirds of the total resistance and so it would drop two-thirds of the battery voltage. Writing it like an equation:

$$ \text{Fraction of total circuit voltage drop} = \text{Fraction of total circuit resistance} $$

The fraction of total voltage drop is just $$ \frac{V_\text{LDR}} {V_\text{battery}} $$ and the fraction of total resistance is just $$ \frac{R_\text{LDR}}{R_\text{LDR} + R_\text{resistor}} $$ so if you accept they are equal you have:

$$ \frac{V_\text{LDR}} {V_\text{battery}} = \frac{R_\text{LDR}}{R_\text{LDR} + R_\text{resistor}} $$

which is just the potential divider equation for resistances. You can now solve for the resistance of the LDR.

Answer (score 0):

You know the voltage drop \$V\$ at the LDR.
Substract that voltage from 3 V.
The difference is the drop at the 1 kΩ resistor.

The total current calculates as \$\frac{V}{1000 Ω}\$.

Then use the LDR voltage drop with the total current using Ohms Law to get the LDR resistance.
Let's say LDR is 1 V. Then \$3V - 1V = 2V\$.

2 volts drop on the 1kΩ . \$\frac{2V}{1000Ω} = .002A\$

LDR is \$\frac{1V}{.002A} = 500Ω\$.